# Inheritance and shared_ptr ref parameters with Boost.Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, binding, boost-python

I've run into an edge case with Boost.Python that seems like it should work but doesn't.

What I have is a Base and a Derived class that I am storing in `std::shared_ptr`'s on the python side. What I would like to do is pass a Derived type `shared_ptr` to a function that accepts a Base `shared_ptr` by reference.

I've done some research and have learned about [implicitly_convertible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853477/boost-python-runtime-error-when-passing-object-of-derived-type-from-python-to-c) and have attempted to employ it to fix the problem but without success (although it does help in some other situations). Passing a Derived to function that accepts a Base& works with this but if they're wrapped in `shared_ptr` then it fails.

What I get currently is the message below:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrRef(Derived) did not match C++ signature:
    acceptBaseSharedPtrRef(std::shared_ptr<(anonymous namespace)::Base> {lvalue})
```

See below for example code:

C++ Binding code

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#define BOOST_PYTHON_USE_GCC_SYMBOL_VISIBILITY 1

#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


namespace
{

  class Base
  {
  };

  class Derived : public Base
  {
  };

  std::shared_ptr<Base> getBaseSharedPtr()
  {
    auto retVal = std::make_shared<Base>();
    std::cout << "Creating Base shared_ptr - " << retVal.get() << std::endl;
    return retVal;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<Derived> getDerivedSharedPtr()
  {
    auto retVal = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    std::cout << "Creating Derived shared_ptr - " << retVal.get() << std::endl;
    return retVal;
  }

  void acceptBaseSharedPtrRef(std::shared_ptr<Base>& base)
  {
    std::cout << "acceptBaseSharedPtrRef() with " << base.get() << std::endl;
  }

  void acceptBaseSharedPtrConstRef(const std::shared_ptr<Base>& base)
  {
    std::cout << "acceptBaseSharedPtrConstRef() with " << base.get() << std::endl;
  }

  void acceptBaseSharedPtrCopy(std::shared_ptr<Base> base)
  {
    std::cout << "acceptBaseSharedPtrCopy() with " << base.get() << std::endl;
  }

  //

  void acceptBaseRef(Base base)
  {

  }

} // namespace

namespace bindings
{
  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test_bed_bindings)
  {
    PyEval_InitThreads();
    Py_Initialize();

    using namespace boost::python;

    def("getBaseSharedPtr",            &::getBaseSharedPtr);
    def("getDerivedSharedPtr",         &::getDerivedSharedPtr);
    def("acceptBaseSharedPtrRef",      &::acceptBaseSharedPtrRef);
    def("acceptBaseSharedPtrConstRef", &::acceptBaseSharedPtrConstRef);
    def("acceptBaseSharedPtrCopy",     &::acceptBaseSharedPtrCopy);

    def("acceptBaseRef",     &::acceptBaseRef);

    class_<Base, std::shared_ptr<Base> >("Base")
        .def(init<>())
        ;

    class_<Derived, bases<Base>, std::shared_ptr<Derived> >("Derived")
        .def(init<>())
        ;

    implicitly_convertible<Derived, Base>();
    implicitly_convertible<std::shared_ptr<Derived>, std::shared_ptr<Base>>();

  } // BOOST_PYTHON

} // namespace bindings
```

Python execution code

```
import test_bed_bindings

baseObj = test_bed_bindings.Base()
derivedObj = test_bed_bindings.Derived()

test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseRef( baseObj )
test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseRef( derivedObj )

baseSharedPtr = test_bed_bindings.getBaseSharedPtr()
derivedSharedPtr = test_bed_bindings.getDerivedSharedPtr()

test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrCopy( baseSharedPtr )
test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrCopy( derivedSharedPtr )

test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrConstRef( baseSharedPtr )
test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrConstRef( derivedSharedPtr )

test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrRef( baseSharedPtr )
test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrRef( derivedSharedPtr )
```

Sample Output

```
Creating Base shared_ptr - 0x276fdb8
Creating Derived shared_ptr - 0x276fde8
acceptBaseSharedPtrCopy() with 0x276fdb8
acceptBaseSharedPtrCopy() with 0x276fde8
acceptBaseSharedPtrConstRef() with 0x276fdb8
acceptBaseSharedPtrConstRef() with 0x276fde8
acceptBaseSharedPtrRef() with 0x276fdb8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.py", line 21, in <module>
    test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrRef( derivedSharedPtr )
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    test_bed_bindings.acceptBaseSharedPtrRef(Derived)
did not match C++ signature:
    acceptBaseSharedPtrRef(std::shared_ptr<(anonymous namespace)::Base> {lvalue})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional.  To reduce the chance of a dangling reference and provide explicit directionality between the languages, Boost.Python will pass the *temporary* object resulting from an *rvalue* conversion by const reference to functions.  The [`implicit_convertible<Source, Target>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/to_from_python_type_conversion/boost_python_implicit_hpp.html) function registers an *rvalue* from-Python conversion.  As the result of the converter is an *rvalue*, one can only accept it by either value or constant reference.

---

When a class is registered via [`boost::python::class_<T, HeldType, Bases>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components.html#high_level_components.boost_python_class_hpp.class_template_class_t_bases_hel) and `HeldType` is wrapping `T`:

- the resulting Python class embeds an instance of `HeldType`
- registers to-Python converter from instances of `T` to an instance of the Python class
- registers *lvalue* from-Python converter for instances of the Python class to instances of `T`
- registers to-Python converter from instances of `HeldType` to Python object
- registers *lvalue* from-Python converter for instances of the Python class to instances of `HeldType`
- for each base in `Bases`, registers *lvalue* from-Python converter for instances of the Python class to instances of `T` in the base (not the base's `HeldType`)
- for each polymorphic base in `Bases`, registers a to-Python converter from instances of `T` held by a base to the Python class

With the following setup:

```cpp
class base {};
class derived: public base {};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  python::class_<base, std::shared_ptr<base>>("Base");
  python::class_<derived, python::bases<base>,
    std::shared_ptr<derived>>("Derived");

  python::implicitly_convertible<std::shared_ptr<derived>,
                                 std::shared_ptr<base>>();
}
```

The following *lvalue* from-Python conversions are possible because the Python object holds an instance of the C++ object:

- `example.Base` to `base`, `base&`, `const base&`, `std::shared_ptr<base>`, `std::shared_ptr<base>&`, and `const std::shared_ptr<base>&`
- `example.Derived`  to `base`, `base&`, `const base&`, `derived`, `derived&`, `const derived&`, `std::shared_ptr<derived>`, `std::shared_ptr<derived>&`, and `const std::shared_ptr<derived>&`

The following to-Python conversions are possible:

- `base` or `std::shared_ptr<base>` to `example.Base`
- `derived` or `std::shared_ptr<derived` to `example.Derived`

If `base` was polymorphic, then the following to-Python conversions would be possible:

- object with dynamic type of `derived*` and static type of `base*` to `example.Derived`
- `std::shared_ptr<base>` holding an instance of `derived` to `example.Derived`

The following *rvalue* conversions is possible due to explicit registration via `implicitly_convertible`:

- `example.Derived` to `std::shared_ptr<base>` and `const std::shared_ptr<base>&`

The difference between an *lvalue* and an *rvalue* conversion is whether or not the target C++ object already exists and is being held in a Python object.  For example, an *lvalue* conversion of `example.Derived` to `base&` is possible because `example.Derived` holds an instance of `derived` which is-a `base`.  On the other hand, an *lvalue* conversion from `example.Derived` to `std::shared_ptr<base>&` is not possible because `example.Derived` holds an instance of `std::shared_ptr<derived>`, which does not inherit from `std::shared_ptr<base>`.  Hence, a `std::shared_ptr<base>` with an unspecified lifetime is constructed and passed as an *rvalue* argument to the exposed function.

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01f0e6a49e0febf1) these conversions:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <memory> // std::shared_ptr

class base {};
class derived: public base {};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<base, std::shared_ptr<base>>("Base");
  python::class_<derived, python::bases<base>, 
    std::shared_ptr<derived>>("Derived");

  python::implicitly_convertible<std::shared_ptr<derived>,
                                 std::shared_ptr<base>>();

  python::def("base_value", +[](base){});
  python::def("base_ref", +[](base&){});
  python::def("base_cref", +[](const base&){});

  python::def("shared_base_value", +[](std::shared_ptr<base>){});
  python::def("shared_base_ref", +[](std::shared_ptr<base>&){});
  python::def("shared_base_cref", +[](const std::shared_ptr<base>&){});

  python::def("derived_value", +[](derived){});
  python::def("derived_ref", +[](derived&){});
  python::def("derived_cref", +[](const derived&){});

  python::def("shared_derived_value", +[](std::shared_ptr<derived>){});
  python::def("shared_derived_ref", +[](std::shared_ptr<derived>&){});
  python::def("shared_derived_cref", +[](const std::shared_ptr<derived>&){});
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> base = example.Base()
>>> example.base_value(base)
>>> example.base_ref(base)
>>> example.base_cref(base)
>>> example.shared_base_value(base)
>>> example.shared_base_ref(base)
>>> example.shared_base_cref(base)
>>> 
>>> derived = example.Derived()
>>> example.base_value(derived)
>>> example.base_ref(derived)
>>> example.base_cref(derived)
>>> example.shared_base_value(derived)
>>> try:
...     got_exception = False
...     example.shared_base_ref(derived)
... except TypeError:
...     got_exception = True
... finally:
...     assert(got_exception)
...
>>> example.shared_base_cref(derived)
>>> example.derived_value(derived)
>>> example.derived_ref(derived)
>>> example.derived_cref(derived)
>>> example.shared_derived_value(derived)
>>> example.shared_derived_ref(derived)
>>> example.shared_derived_cref(derived)
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation of the inner workings. I'd worked out most of this from research but I wasn't sure if I was missing something. I guess from here I'll be implementing a workaround of some kind.